# Mail library for raspberry 2 running windows 10

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi

I would like to send a mail, using Google's SMTP, on a Raspberry 2 model b using windows 10 iot.

In a "normal" x64 application, I know a lot of ways, but it seems like there is very limited support for Nuget packages in general on the ARM processor.

All the libraries I've tried so far results in:

`<library> is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm).`

Do you have any suggestion on a DLL that lets me send a mail on the C# ARM app, or am I out of luck?

Comment: Have you tried [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit)? That seems to compile fine for UWP on ARM.